# How do I convert a Java Bean to a JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, javabeans

I know that a `JsonObject` in the package `org.json` could create a `JsonObject` with
a constructor whose argument is an object, but I could't find it in Eclipse.

[image: As the image shows]

After adding the `org.json` dependency, below is how it's showing up.

[image]

Comment: can expalin bit more are you looking for command or is there any issue with your eclipse?

Comment: What JSON library are you using? if it is in Maven, can you show your maven dependency ?

Comment: @Vebbie I've use org.json dependency in my pom.xml.

Comment: @abhinavxeon I'm looking for a constructor who can create a JsonObject with a java bean.

Comment: Not sure about this missing constructor issue. But one more way to convert Java bean to json object is using `jackson-databind`.

Comment: @Vebbie Okay I'll try it later, thank for the suggestion~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not able to see that constructor is since the `JSONObject` class that you are using is from the `android-json` package. You can see the same constructors in the [Android JSONObject doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

To get the `JSONObject` that you're expecting, you would need to add the dependency of `org.json` as below (either Maven or Gradle)

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle dependency**

```
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
```

Then import **this** `JSONObject` class and you would see the constructor that you actually want.

Comment: @wangzewei have you added this dependency to your maven pom or gradle file?

Comment: yeah I've add the dependency to my maven pom.

Comment: you can check the result after adding the dependency,I don't know which one should I choose.

Comment: the image named 'after add dependency' is the screenshot after adding the dependency.

Comment: @wangzewei After adding the dependency, make sure that the dependency is downloaded, then import the JSONObject of `org.json`. You would find the one that you want.

Comment: How could I know the dependency is download or not??

Comment: @wangzewei you'd be able to see `org.json` on the external libraries section of your  project on the IDE with the version that you've provided on your pom or gradle. Either way, just rebuild the project so that it downloads the new dependency that you've added.

Comment: oh I've successfully found the org.json package in the maven dependencies library, and I've seen the constructor I'm looking for, but I still can't find the constructor in the suggest list...what a strange thing..

Comment: @wangzewei just rebuild the project and see if you can see the constructor on the suggestions, I can see the constructor on my Intellij IDE

Comment: You mean refresh the project??

Comment: @wangzewei rebuild the project

Comment: Okay I've seen it on the suggestions list, thank you very much~~By the way, how to rebulid project on ecplise??...

Comment: Is there any option which can rebulid project soon?

Comment: @wangzewei if you have maven project, `mvn clean install` will build the project. Also please accept the answer if it solved your query. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I see.Sure~

Answer (score 0):

You can used following method for convert your java bean object into JSON Object. I have added few data type, Also used common format to add into json object. You can customize wish to want. You just want to pass Object reference to this method.

```
private JSONObject beanToJSON(Object bean) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        System.out.println(fields.length);

        for (Field f : fields) {
            String field = f.getName();
            Class params[] = {};
            Object paramsObj[] = {};

            Method method = bean.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get" + StringUtils.capitalise(field), params);
            Object v = method.invoke(bean, paramsObj);

            Class t = f.getType();

            if (t == boolean.class && Boolean.FALSE.equals(v)) {
                json.accumulate(field, v.toString());

            } else if (t.isPrimitive() && ((Number) v).doubleValue() == 0) {
                json.accumulate(field, v.toString());

            } else if (t.isPrimitive() && ((Number) v).intValue() == 0) {
                json.accumulate(field, v.toString());

            } else if (t == String.class) {
                json.accumulate(field, v.toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```